# Convert pixels of a picture on GPS coordinates

Tags: java, android, gps, drone.io

I'm doing a project on Android for measuring areas of land through photographs taken by a drone.
I have an aerial photograph that contains a GPS coordinate. For practical purposes I assume that coordinate represents the central pixel of the picture.

I need to move pixel by pixel in the picture to reach the corners and know what GPS coordinate represent the corners of the

I have no idea about how to achieve it. I have searched but can not find anything similar to my problem.
Thank You.

[enter link description here](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/CCUat4PXQzM6FrlcMhb5SWCBeYrjWtSzNR8xZIwZrizNWBt8EFJu_o9Hhd9GEGyVtL7Ryd9E=w1896-h835-rw)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the altitude at which the photo was taken and the camera maximum capture angle I believe you can determine (through trigonometry) the deviation of each pixel from the center, in meters, and then determine the GPS coordinate of it.

Answer (score 1):

According to my knowledge,

Height of the drone also matter so first of all with the central coordinate you also need at what height drone take that picture.

Now you need to perform some experiment with reference picture between two known GPS coordinate of two points of picture. Change the height of the drone and plot the number of pixels between two coordinate wrt to the height of drone. Doing some curve fitting and get the function between two variable.

Using the above function you can calculate the "change in GPS coordinate per pixel" at the particular height and by using this parameter we can easily deduce the GPS of picture taken by drone at particular height.

I don't know whether the solution works or not. But this my idea you can use this and develop further.

Thanks